Why openocd corrupt simplelink cc13x2 radio periphery?
I use in project with simplelink cc1312 mcu (on test board from TI) + vscode + gdb. I can build, flash and debug with these tools. But radio periphery not working correctly after flash(and start debug) program. As I think RF periphery registers not in initial state, that's why radio do not(boot bit in register already 1) get interrupt after boot, and program hang up(cos wait radio initialization). I try build same project on Code Composer Studio and all works fine.
What could be the problem?

This branch try to fix problem with reset. I don't know why this fix not in last version of openocd.
https://review.openocd.org/c/openocd/+/5658
